# Solving for $y$ in $y= 14x + 1000 = y= 16x + 800$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Given $y= 14x + 1000 = y= 16x + 800$, solve for $y$.

I think I have it: 
$x= 100$. Subbing that in would leave me with:

$y = 14x + 1000$

$y = 14 \cdot 100 + 1000$

$y = 2400$

$y = 16x + 800$

$y = 16 \cdot 100 + 800$
$y = 2400$

the lines break even at $y= 2400$ and $x= 100$

Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: What have you tried? Is there a part in particular you are having difficulty with?

Comment: I have goten as far as 16x+800=14x1000

Comment: the teacher had trouble teaching because the class was to disruptive so I am unsure how to progress this equation

Comment: Your edited answer looks correct. Good job Vector!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** You know that $y=14x+1000$ and you know that $y=16x+800.$ You want to either use elimination or substitution to solve for either $x$ or for $y$, and then back substitute to find the other variable.

An example is for two equations: $y=5x+2$ and $y=2x-1$. I'll proceed by the substitution method. Since we know both equations are equal to $y$, instead of writing $y$, we can write the other equation instead, since their values are equal to $y$. So we get:

$5x+2=2x-1\\\implies 3x=-3\\\implies x=-1$.

So now we know the $x$ value. We can substitute this into the equation (either equation). I'm going to choose to substitute $x=-1$ into the equation $y=2x-1$. This gives us $y=2(-1)-1=-2-1=-3$. So in my example, $x=-1$ and $y=-3$. The process for your question is similar.

Comment: Way to add the extra detail +1

Answer (score 3):

$y= 14x + 1000 = y= 16x + 800$

$\implies 14x+1000=16x+800$

Now solve for $x$.

Once you have $x$, you can just plug it back into either equation for $y$. Does that make sense?

EDIT:

You are at this point:

$14x+1000=16x+800$

By solve for $x$, I mean isolate it on one side of the equation. You can do this by eliminating one of the $x$ terms from one side. Let's eliminate $14x$:

$\hspace{3mm}14x+1000=16x+800$

$-14x \hspace{15mm} -14x$

$=0 \hspace{3 mm}+1000=2x+800$

$\implies 1000=2x+800$.

Now how do you eliminate the $800$? Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: yes but like I stated in the post above that is as far as i got in the equation (in reply to kbball)

Comment: FYI - from the second line, you need to "solve a linear equation". That is something that many here can teach, but you might be better served by a web search/YouTube/khan academy...